# Getting Uninitialized Constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Seems that made some mistake in the model

```
class LineItemAddons < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :line_item
  has_one :addon_type_value
  attr_accessible :quantity, :received, :snapshot_price, :status, :line_item_id, :addon_type_value_id

class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :design
  belongs_to :cart
  belongs_to :designer_order
  belongs_to :return 
  belongs_to :return_designer_order
  has_many :line_item_addons

class AddonTypeValue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :design
  belongs_to :addon_type
  belongs_to :line_item_addon
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :position, :price, :addon_type_id, :design_id, :quantity
```

Getting unintialized constant for line_item_addons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake while generating the model

the class name should LineItemAddon not LineItemAddons

Sorry Guys

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
class AddonTypeValue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :design
  belongs_to :addon_type
  belongs_to :line_item_addons
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to describe association `belongs_to` with `has_one`.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association

Try to remove `belongs_to :line_item_addon` from `AddonTypeValue` model